# Load data from dask area in parellel in chunks

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, python-xarray

I have a large xarray dataset loaded in a dask dataframe which contains data over both quite a large spatial and temporal range. What I'm trying to do is load this data into memory using dask by splitting it into smaller chunks and loading these in in parallel. Below is an example code of what I'm trying to do:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

def chunk(ds,x_ends,y_ends):
    '''
    Function which takes a large dataset which has been lazily loaded and specified
    indices within the dataset, and cuts out the chunk and loads it into memory. 
    '''

    chunk = ds.isel(x=slice(x_ends[0],x_ends[1]),y=slice(y_vals[0],y_vals[1]))

    with ProgressBar():
        chunk = chunk.compute()
    return chunk

dval = np.random.randint(5,size=[10,100,100])
x = np.linspace(0,100,101,dtype=int)
y = np.linspace(0,100,101,dtype=int)
time = np.linspace(0,10,11,dtype=int)

data = xr.DataArray(dval,coords=[time,x,y],dims=['time','x','y'])

x_vals = np.arange(0,len(data.x),1000)
x_vals = np.append(x_vals,len(data.x))
y_vals = np.arange(0,len(data.y),1000)
y_vals = np.append(y_vals,len(data.y))

for i in range(len(x_vals)-1):
    for j in range(len(y_vals)-1):
        chunk(data,[x_vals[i],x_vals[i+1]],[y_vals[j],y_vals[j+1]])
```

This does what I want it to do, but obviously not in parallel and isn't great with the double for loop. This will slot into a larger function where the data will have other operations applied on it. I also realise that the DataArray in the example isn't a dasked array.

I previously tried using the dask.distributed Client class, but that broke the .compute() function. I feel like there is probably a relatively simple answer which I'm just looking in the wrong place for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function exists to make a daskified, chunked version of your Xarray: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.chunk.html
That would do what you want for the toy example. Operations on that data would then be done chunk-by-chunk, and probably parallelise well.

However, you are more typically wanting to chunk your data on load rather than split up an array already in memory. Most of the xarray loading functions allow you to specify `chunks=`, which will automatically make the internal data model dasky, and give you parallel and/or out-of-core processing. The format `zarr` is particularly friendly for this kind of operation, as each data chunk is stored in a different file, and can be seamlessly loaded from a remote storage system, if desired.